# Method ends before $.getJson finishes running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow code using jQUery's getjson methods

```
function Share(){
var title = 'Hello';
var description = 'hi description';
var url = "www.facebook.com"

$.getJSON("http://getTitle/1", function(data){
        title = data.Name;
});
callShare(title,description,url,imageUrl);
}


function callShare(title,description,url,imageUrl){
window.open(
        'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]='+title+'&p[summary]='+description+' &p[url]='+url+'&p[images][0]='+imageUrl+'','facebook-share-dialog',
        'width=626,height=436')}
```

However, it seems that the method finishes running and does the callShare function before the getJson method has finished running. Would require some help here. I understand that there might be duplicate question here and I apologize but I am not able to apply it here.

Thanks

Comment: ajax is asynchronous so you need to use the callback if you want the code to run when the call finishes

Comment: Duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call). Please show us how you tried to apply those solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.getJSON("http://getTitle/1", function(data){
        title = data.Name;
        callShare(title,description,url,imageUrl);
});
```

Being an async function `$.getJson()` doesn't wait for the response and executes the next line. 
If you want to do some things after the response has been received from the server put it in the success function. Like I have mentioned in the code.

if you also want to execute code on error or before sending the request. Use `$.ajax()` instead

Comment: this does make sense, but what if i have to make multiple getJson calls

Comment: @LionelKoh Then you wrap the calls to `$.getJSON` inside [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), which executes a callback once *all* of the requests complete

Answer (score 0):

Althoug the question has been answered by [Parv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794226/parv-sharma) but here are some explanation

First of all the correct way to call functions in such senarios

```
$.getJSON("http://getTitle/1", function(data){
     title = data.Name;
     callShare(title,description,url,imageUrl);
});
```

Now the question is why?

`$.getJSON` is an extension of `$.ajax` method i.e. Asynchronous, so the browsers expect of waiting for the request to complete by `$.getJSON` they move on to the next line of codes so that the user dont get stuck with lock browser waiting for a request to complete.

Now what is the solution in that case?

Such Asynchronous requests have a or couple of special methods called [call backs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), so all you need is to call such methods in those call backs that are required to be called after the `successful` `failed` or `complete` of the request, you will find more in the above link

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` is just a shorthand for `$.ajax`. As others pointed out, its an `async` call which will run in a separate thread(kind of) and rest of the code will keep on executing without worrying for the `JSON` result.

So you can add a `success` function which will be called when the `async` call succeeds. You can use `$.ajax` too.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: callShare(title,description,url,imageUrl),
  error: alert('error');
});
```

I use `$.ajax` because it gives more clarity over the things that are happening.